# Can't pass varable to sqlite in bash script (while other variables do pass)

Tags: sql, bash, sqlite, shell

So I have a digikam database I'm messing around with. I have converted some vid files from MPG to MP4 (and lazily decided to just append ".mp4" to the ".mpg" filename (so .mpg.mp4 is the ugly result...) instead of replacing the original extension, which actually makes this a whole lot easier code-wise), imported them back and want to copy the tags over to the converted files. The database is a sqlite3 database. The ImageTags table contains the imageid field (matching the Images.id field) and the tagid field. It's a one-to-many deal, so if your imageid is 123 and you have tagids 3 and 4 assigned, you'd get two rows of data, one for each tag.

Since sqlite doesn't support variables, I found (thanks to SO) how to quote variables from a shell script to a query. This code is rough and is only up to the point of trying to get the right output, not the point of adding to the db, but the idea is to get the converted mp4 file id from the database, get the original file id, then replace the ImageTags.imageid with the new one, and then add them as a new rows to the database in whatever way, haven't decided...below assumes a test case of just spitting out a csv file and then I can add that to the table, but I think I'd want to do this in some INSERT-wise fashion, but that's not where I'm stuck; I've not written that part yet and this is still in POC status.

I have nearly the entire code working to this point, as ugly as it is, except for one part: this specific line doesn't work.

```
SELECT REPLACE(ImageTags.imageid,\"${original_imageid}\",\"${mp4_imageid}\"),ImageTags.tagid
```

So the output of the below code is, for example:

```
mp4 file is 89877
original file is 39967
39967,13
39967,3
39967,152
39967,212
```

What I was hoping was

```
mp4 file is 89877
original file is 39967
89877,13
89877,3
89877,152
89877,212
```

So that REPLACE statement isn't accepting the variables. I have done tests with static values and it works with static values. What is puzzling me is that the rest of the SQL happily accepts the

```
\"${file}\"
```

statement without issue, but it seems to choke on

```
\"${original_imageid}\",\"${mp4_imageid}\"
```

I have played around with various single quotes, no quotes, no braces, etc. I am wondering if this should just be rewritten in Python, but I am afraid I'd encounter the same problem. I am wondering if this is a matter of in what order the statements are processed or something. Or worse yet, this is wildly outside of how the REPLACE statement is intended to work. I've read the docs and numerous examples on how to use REPLACE and they don't seem to have any examples of working with variables in a shell script.

Code (don't hate me):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
db=/home/john/media/digikam4.db 
find /home/john/media -type f -iname "*.mp*g" -print0 | 
    while read -d $'\0' file
        do
            mp4_imageid=$(sqlite3 -ascii ${db} "
SELECT Images.id
FROM Images
JOIN Albums
ON Images.album = Albums.id
JOIN AlbumRoots
ON Albums.albumRoot = AlbumRoots.id
WHERE AlbumRoots.specificPath || Albums.relativePath || \"/\" || Images.name
IS \"${file}\" || \".mp4\"
")
echo "mp4 file is $mp4_imageid"
            
            original_imageid=$(sqlite3 -ascii ${db} "
SELECT Images.id
FROM Images
JOIN Albums 
ON Images.album = Albums.id
JOIN AlbumRoots
ON Albums.albumRoot = AlbumRoots.id
WHERE AlbumRoots.specificPath || Albums.relativePath || \"/\" || Images.name
IS \"${file}\"
")
echo "original file is $original_imageid"

            sqlite3 -csv ${db} "
SELECT REPLACE(ImageTags.imageid,\"${original_imageid}\",\"${mp4_imageid}\"),ImageTags.tagid
FROM ImageTags
JOIN Images 
ON Images.id = ImageTags.imageid
JOIN Albums
ON Images.album = Albums.id
JOIN AlbumRoots
ON Albums.albumRoot = AlbumRoots.id
WHERE AlbumRoots.specificPath || Albums.relativePath || \"/\" || Images.name
IS \"${file}\"
"

done
```

Comment: You should use single quotes for sql strings. And you forgot to include any error messages...

Comment: That's the thing, no errors. If I replace the double quotes around the final sql block with single quotes, I get
Error: unrecognized token: "\"

Comment: @Shawn, So I replaced the final block quotes with singles and got rid of all the backslashes, and it returns nothing for that block.
(Should be the tags here but it's absent). How would I pass variables if it's single quoted?

Comment: No, strings in sql statements. (Though I feel heredocs are best for including sql in a shell script instead of quotes)

Comment: @Shawn You mean like:
    SELECT REPLACE(ImageTags.imageid,'$original_imageid','$mp4_imageid'),ImageTags.tagid
?
Let me try a here doc. My v1 of this had it, and I dropped it based on SO :P

Comment: So I tried a here document and single quotes and while it runs, the original wrong output is still presenting. Hmmm...

Comment: Yes, like that. SQL uses single quotes for strings, double quotes to quote identifiers like table and column names. (Sqlite may or may not also accept double quoted strings depending on how it's compiled; better to stick to the standard. See https://sqlite.org/quirks.html#double_quoted_string_literals_are_accepted for details)

Comment: So this is my new code (the block quote isn't working here for some reason):
     sqlite3 -csv ${db} << EOF
    SELECT REPLACE(ImageTags.imageid,'$original_imageid','$mp4_imageid'),ImageTags.tagid
    FROM ImageTags
    JOIN Images 
    ON Images.id = ImageTags.imageid
    JOIN Albums
    ON Images.album = Albums.id
    JOIN AlbumRoots
    ON Albums.albumRoot = AlbumRoots.id
    WHERE AlbumRoots.specificPath || Albums.relativePath || "/" || Images.name
    IS "${file}"
    EOF

Unfortunately the output is the same as the OP

Comment: You should update your question instead of trying to put extended chunks of code in comments.

Comment: Your link was talking about sql literals and this got me thinking about the problem in a different angle:  I got it working.... I was using -ascii on the variables, I needed -quote. I'll post, update and close this. The problem was how my variables were being seen by sqlite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is that I was using -ascii. I should have been using -quote. It gives the expected output now.

So it needed the data in the variables set as sql literals, and the -quote parameter works
So this code works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
db=/home/john/media/digikam4.db 
find /home/john/media -type f -iname "*.mp*g" -print0 | 
    while read -d $'\0' file
        do
            mp4_imageid=$(sqlite3 -quote ${db} "
SELECT Images.id
FROM Images
JOIN Albums
ON Images.album = Albums.id
JOIN AlbumRoots
ON Albums.albumRoot = AlbumRoots.id
WHERE AlbumRoots.specificPath || Albums.relativePath || \"/\" || Images.name
IS \"${file}\" || \".mp4\"
")
echo "mp4 file is $mp4_imageid"
            
            original_imageid=$(sqlite3 -quote ${db} "
SELECT Images.id
FROM Images
JOIN Albums 
ON Images.album = Albums.id
JOIN AlbumRoots
ON Albums.albumRoot = AlbumRoots.id
WHERE AlbumRoots.specificPath || Albums.relativePath || \"/\" || Images.name
IS \"${file}\"
")
echo "original file is $original_imageid"

            sqlite3 -csv ${db} "
SELECT REPLACE(ImageTags.imageid,\"${original_imageid}\",\"${mp4_imageid}\"),ImageTags.tagid
FROM ImageTags
JOIN Images 
ON Images.id = ImageTags.imageid
JOIN Albums
ON Images.album = Albums.id
JOIN AlbumRoots
ON Albums.albumRoot = AlbumRoots.id
WHERE AlbumRoots.specificPath || Albums.relativePath || \"/\" || Images.name
IS \"${file}\"
"

done
```